# Ruby Regex - matching a list in text

Tags: ruby, regex

So my goal is simple, parse a message with a list, such as these:

```
show tom and harry
show tom, dick and harry
show tom, dick, jane and harry
```

My problem is that I can write a regex which matches a list with or without the middle elements...

```
/show (\w+)[, (\w+)]* and (\w+)/
```

In this case it appears to match tom and harry, but dick and jane are not returned as arguments.

Example (from rubulus)

[image: regex matching missing middle elements of list]

It appears the round brackets within the squared brackets are ignored. Does anyone know how I can match these?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for answering promptly, I had prematurely published the question by mistake. 

There's a bit more in the description, but basically I want to match every item in the written list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
(?:(?<=and )|(?<=, )|(?<=show ))(\w+)
```

[**Regex Demo Link**](http://rubular.com/r/MP4haSQ3kF)

**OR**

```
(?<=and |, |show )\w+
```

Comment: This returns commas too, something he didn't ask for I guess:)

Comment: This works, but requires some later processing to handle strings like ', dick, jane'

Comment: @AJFaraday But that string does not contain `show` as per the input. Do you wish to include `,` in your output?

Comment: I need to match that the string begins with 'show' (which differentiates this from other message types) but not include it in the output. 

Ideally I would input `show tom, dick, jane and harry` and it would return `['tom','dick','jane','harry']`. 

This regex returned ['tom',', dick, jane', 'harry'], which is something I could use and then process.

Comment: The last variant `/(?:(?<=and )|(?<=, )|(?<=show ))(\w+)/` works for me. There's a slight oddity in that it matches the and if there's a comma before the and (as people with poor grammar will add), but it's easily enough to work with. Thanks!

Comment: @AJFaraday Glad to hear it worked :) I wrote it assuming that the input string is always in the correct format.

Comment: I believe that can be simplified to `/(?<=and |, |show )\w+/`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I dont think so, look behinds usually dont allow variable lenght patterns

Comment: You are correct that Ruby doesn`t support variable-length lookarounds, but what I suggested is not variable-length.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do it:

```
a = "show tom, dick, jane and harry"
arr = a.split(/ |, /)
# => ["show", "tom", "dick", "jane", "and", "harry"]
arr.reject! {|item| item =~ /show|and/i }
# => ["tom", "dick", "jane", "harry"]
```

or

```
a = "show tom, dick, harry, alpha, beta, tango and charlie"
arr = a.split(/ |, /)
arr.reject! {|item| item =~ /show|and/i }
# => ["tom", "dick", "harry", "alpha", "beta", "tango", "charlie"]
```

Comment: This would work fine, although I'm doing it in a context which involves saving the regex to the database and matching all message forms the same way.

Comment: No arguments here, it does work, and I would usually avoid regex at any cost ;)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is the most elegant solution, but it *should* work (as I've only tested it with regex101.com):

```
show (?'first'\w+)(?'comma'(, \w+)*)(?: and (?'and'\w+))?
```

Then you'll get an object with a field with the name of 'first', and possibly one with 'comma' and one with 'and'.

To extract all names in the 'comma' group, you have split the string on ', ' (comma-space) (the first member of the array will be empty)

I hope you will find this useful!

Comment: This would work after processing the second member of the array further, as you said. I have now found a direct regex solution.

Comment: Really? Can you post it please? :)

Comment: @nu11p01n73R provided it `/(?:(?<=and )|(?<=, )|(?<=show ))(\w+)/`